# Error in PHP mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two of this codes:

```
if($result=mysql_query($select))
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

I want mysqli of this codes

Comment: Please check this link [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-array.html).

Comment: We're here to help, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_db");
    $sql="select * from table_name";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        }
    }

Please try this one
```